# Linux alias with checking directory

Tags: linux, bash

How can I do alias which check if I'm in directory "python27" and when not it will be go to that directory, run some script and come back to home directory? When I'm in "python27" directory it should just run script and come back to home directory. I mean something like this:

```
alias p="if [ pwd != /home/myname ] then cd python27 && python $1 && cd ~ else python $1 && cd ~ fi"
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an alias, use a function instead.

You don't need to check whether you're in the `python27` directory, just `cd` there, run the script, and `cd` back home.

Something like this, with minimal checking:

```
p() {
    if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
        echo >&2 "need an argument"
        return 1
    fi
    if ! cd /full/path/to/python27; then
        echo >&2 "can't cd to python27"
        return 1
    fi
    python "$1"
    cd ~
}
```

You could also use `python "$@"` instead of `python "$1"` in case you need to pass more arguments (e.g., options).

Comment: Where I should write this function?

Comment: @user6390359: either directly in the terminal (and that would be valid only for this session); or paste it at the end of your `.bashrc` file: then it'll be loaded each time you open up a new terminal.